# How to choose the most recommended Junos release for MX router

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos

How to choose the most recommended Junos release for MX router? I need to choose a Junos OS release to update my Juniper MX960 routers from release 18.1R3, but I cannot find a procedure or best practice on how to choose the most recommended version of Junos OS in the Juniper documentation as Cisco has with the management of IOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suggested release (previously known as recommended junos versions) should give you a hand. However it will vary depending on the setup you have(cards and features.)

More or less words from the KB, note that due to the uniqueness Juniper recommends that all customers A) read the associated Release Notes...

Standard for MX Series as per the chart in the suggested releases link is Junos 17.3R3-S6. Not sure how you landed on 18.1.

1. Check the [Suggested Releases KB](https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB21476)
2. Use the [Feature explorer](https://apps.juniper.net/feature-explorer/select-software.html?swName=Junos%20OS&typ=1#family=&pid=11310960&platform=MX960&rel=18.1R3&sid=943&stat=0.02541014078310766&swName=Junos%20OS)
3. Check [Release notes](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/information-products/topic-collections/release-notes/18.1/index.html)
4. Check with local team and [JTAC](https://support.juniper.net/support/requesting-support/)

Answer (score 0):

There is [Juniper JTAC recommended firmware](https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB21476&actp=METADATA) KB exist. You can refer to this document to choose recommended version.